# nginx summarize similar directory paths

Tags: nginx, web-server, web-hosting

I've been experimenting a lot with my nginx settings to block access to any unwanted directories, but it is really annoying for me to add a couple of new lines each time I add some directory. I've been looking at several forums, but none of the syntax stated seems to work. I've tried syntax `^~ /(dir|dir2)/`, `^~ (/dir|/dir2)/`, `^~ (/dir/|/dir2/)` etc., but like I said, none of those work, the only solution seems to be restricting every single directory, which looks really awful imho.

If you know about any kind of syntax, that could potentially work in this case, I would really appreciate answer in any form.

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
nginx ver.: nginx/1.14.2

```
location ^~ /includes/ {
        deny all;
        return 403;
        }
    location ^~ /vendor/ {
        deny all;
        return 403;
        }
    location ^~ /packages/ {
        deny all;
        return 403;
        }
    location ^~ /res/ {
        deny all;
        return 403;
        }
    location ^~ /styles/ {
        deny all;
        return 403;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^~` means that nginx will use the prefix match always, without checking regular expressions.

To match using regular expression, you need to use:

```
location ~ ^/(?:includes|vendor|packages|res|styles)/ {
```

- `~` tells nginx that this is a regular expression
- `^` matches the start of request string
- `/` matches URI start slash
- `()` normally declares a capturing group. However, the `?:` prevents capturing
- `|` is used as "or" inside the group.